# odata and webapi together in the same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, routes, odata

I have the ticketController

```
public class ticketsController : ODataController
{
}
```

Is it possible to have this:

```
GET     /api/tickets?$skip={record_to_skip}&$top={pageSize}
GET     /api/tickets/{id}
PUT     /api/tickets/{id}
DELETE  /api/request/{id}
```

First GET method uses odata routing, the second GET, PUT, and POST uses web api routing

Thanks

Comment: Since `/api/tickets/{id}` looks like an OData url, you will struggle to be able to split them up, although it may be possible. However, I don't understand why you would want to do this anyway as OData has a way of doing all of the things that you have mentioned - `/api/tickets(id)` - why not just use that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you have to use an OData attribute.  Your controller should inherit from ApiController not ODataController and on the method/action you want to query paint it with the OData 'Queryable' attribute, check this out for more details:

https://ovaismehboob.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/adding-queryable-support-to-asp-net-web-api-controller-action-methods/

Also if you search for OData queryable attribute you should get a a load of information back